# How to get source code of specific URL in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to get source code of specific URL in JavaScript.

I can get source code of current web page with this code:

```
document.documentElement;
```

But I don't know how can I get source code of specific URL.

(I want to use `documentElement` anyway)

Comment: you can use fetch, and e= createElement, than e.innerHTML = fetch response, and than the e will contains your source (will work only if cors is enabled), can you explain more ?

Comment: `documentElement` gives you DOM element, it isn't source code, and can't get you anything not relating to the current document.

Comment: Try [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) if your script is in browser, try [http.request](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_url_options_callback) if you want it in Node